# Vaadin filter Date Column

Tags: java, vaadin

I am using Vaadin 15. In my application I am using a grid, which uses a dataprovider (data) to show a bunch of different columns. Further, I am using a filter to filter all columns. One Column consists of dates, with my current Filter Function i can not filter ranges.

I am very new to Java and programming in general. This is the filter function I use currently.

```
TextField cas=getFilters(casColumn,filter);
cas.addValueChangeListener(event-> data.addFilter(dataRecord-> StringUtils.containsIgnoreCase(dataRecord.getCas(), cas.getValue())));
```

Now I would like to also be able to filter ranges of dates. So in the filter TextField a date is given and everything till today will be shown, everything older than the date will not be shown.

Thanks for your help. Tipps for some literature on how to do it are also appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am using Vaadin 15.

Just pointing out that it makes little sense to use Vaadin 15, as it is not supported anymore. The latest version Vaadin 21.

With the newest Vaadin versions if you are using in memory data provider Grid is set up using

```
GridListDataView<Data> dataView = setITems(data); // where data is a collection of
```

items

Then you can set the filter you use via dataView, say

```
textField.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
     dataView.setFilter(item-> item.getProperty().equals(event.getValue));
});
```

Note, if you have data provider from callbacks, then above method does not apply for you , instead filtering is done as follows, i.e. providing a query that can use the value of the filter

```
    TextField filter = new TextField("Filter");
    filter.setValueChangeMode(ValueChangeMode.LAZY);
    filter.addValueChangeListener(event -> {
        grid.setItems(query -> personService
                .fetch(query.getOffset(), query.getLimit(), event.getValue()).stream(),query -> personService.count(event.getValue()));
    });
```